# Running Perl script accidentally locked a folder

Tags: linux, perl, chmod

I have a Perl script which has the following code

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
chmod -R 775,"path-to-current-folder";
```

Upon running this script, I am unable to access the current folder (and open this script of course) anymore. When seeing the folder in Konqueror, there is an additional lock in the folder icon. Can anyone tell me what happened and how can I undo this?

I have checked the permission of this folder, apparently it was changed to `d---------`. I have solved this problem by resetting the permission, yet it would be great if anyone could explain why this happened. Thanks.

Comment: Become root and change it back.  Then carefully review `perldoc -f chmod`.

Comment: I suspect what you did caused chmod to interpret `-R` as the mode, i.e. `0`, and then try to apply it to files named '775' and "path-to-current-folder".

Comment: @xxfelixxx almost, not quite. `-R` is one of the [file test operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html); `-R 775` is the result of the test "is the file named `775` readable by the RUID?" which is probably false because there is no file named `775`. Then that false becomes 0.

Comment: (if it did exist and was readable, the true value of 1 would give a mode of `d--------x` which is hardly more useful)

Comment: Good call hobbs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the 'chmod' shell command with  the 'chmod' perl function.  The latter takes a single list as a parameter the first element of which must be the numeric code experessed in octal.  From `perldoc -f chmod` ;

```
  chmod LIST
           Changes the permissions of a list of files.  The first element
           of the list must be the numeric mode, which should probably be
           an octal number, and which definitely should not be a string of
           octal digits: 0644 is okay, but "0644" is not.  Returns the
           number of files successfully changed.  See also "oct" if all
           you have is a string.

               $cnt = chmod 0755, "foo", "bar";
               chmod 0755, @executables;
           ... etc ...
```

The former - that is, the shell - has a `-R` switch.  See `man chmod` for details.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way for a Perl script to recursively change permissions of all files under a directory?

Comment: As far as I know, no - not directly via builtins.  Obviously a "system" call to "chmod -R" would do it or alternatively, you could use the File::Find module to find files meeting whatever criteria you have and apply the chmod via the so-called &wanted function.